# Drupal 7 calendar_row_plugin is missing, Calendar Block error

Tags: php, date, drupal, drupal-7, calendar

Hello I tried to install Calendar module, but not everything is working. 
Drupal shows me the following error on Calendar Events site:

```
'calendar_plugin_style: The calendar row plugin is required when using the calendar style, but it is missing.'
```

I have enabled   ***Date API, Date, Date All Day, Date Popup, Calendar, Views, Views UI, CCK*** and some more modules  *(like **Hashtags** etc.)* .

Answer (score 0):

Change the format to Calendar and change to Calendar Entities instead of fields in Show as displayed in below image,

[image: Calendar With Drupal]

For data to be popped up into the calendar, the date in content type has to be Date ISO.

If you want to fresh start then follow this article,

[Calendar With Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477602)